# Set type description in typescript vuejs

Tags: typescript, vue.js, storybook

This throws `'description' does not exist in PropValidator`

```
export default Vue.extend( {
  name: 'something',
  props: {
    'backgroundColor': {
      type: String,
      description: 'What background color to use'
     },
```

To get this in storybook
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is https://github.com/vue-styleguidist/vue-styleguidist/tree/dev/packages/vue-docgen-api#props

```
export default Vue.extend( {
  name: 'something',
  props: {
     /**
     * 'What background color to use'
     */
    'backgroundColor': {
      type: String
     },
```

Has to be multi-line comment inline comment doesn't work